# Multivariable calculus: Can two trajectories of a vector field ever cross each other?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative, vector-fields

I'm taking a multivariable calculus class online. For one of the homework assignments, we learned about trajectories and field vectors. The question displayed in the image is asking me about whether two trajectories of a vector field can ever cross each other. I don't think they can because when you differentiate a function at a certain point you only get one derivative, so you would only have one vector at that point. I could be wrong. What's the right answer?

[picture of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts0Z6.png)

Comment: Your intuition is right!

Comment: The answer is no, because of uniqueness of solution to the trajectory ordinary differential equation, which allows you to deduce that a trajectory is uniquely determined by its starting point. If $F$ is the vector field, and $x(t)$ is a trajectory, it means that $x'(t) = F(x(t))$ for all $t$, and by theory of ODE, we know that the value $x(0)$ uniquely determines the entire trajectory $x$.